# Objects created in method not available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm working with JavaFX for the first time for a school project so the chances are I'm doing something obvious wrong.

Inside my controller class I have a method (customerSU) which creates a new Customer and Lesson object my other methods which use these new Customer and Lesson objects have an error 'cannot resolve symbol 'cust1''.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

 @FXML
 Button btn1Home, btn2Home, btn1SHome, btn1THome, btnStudentSU, btn1SHHome, btnBookLesson, btnAttendLesson, btnCancelLessons;

public void homeToSHome() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StudentSignIn.fxml"));

    Stage window = (Stage) btn1Home.getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
}

 public void homeToTHome() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TutorSignIn.fxml"));

    Stage window = (Stage) btn2Home.getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
}

public void SHomeToHome() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));

    Stage window = (Stage) btn1SHome.getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
}

public void THomeToHome() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));

    Stage window = (Stage) btn1THome.getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
}

public void SHHomeToHome()throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));

    Stage window = (Stage) btn1SHHome.getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
}

public void customerSU() throws IOException {
    Customer cust1 = new Customer(SUFirstName.getText(), SUSurname.getText(), SUEmail.getText());
    Lesson lesson1 = new Lesson();


    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StudentHome.fxml"));

    Stage window = (Stage) btnStudentSU.getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
}

public void bookLesson() throws IOException {
    String response;
    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the name of the lesson you wish to sign up for.");

    lesson1.BookALesson(cust1, response);
}

public void attendLesson() throws  IOException {
    lesson1.attendALesson();
}

public void customerLessonDetails() throws IOException {
    lesson1.lessonDetails();
}

public void cancelLessons() throws IOException {
    lesson1.cancelLessons();
}
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Since you have declared cust1 in costumerSu() method it is visible only there and to other methods they dont exist , the only reason of this error you are facing is it that you are trying to access it from another method bookLesson .

Comment: Take a closer look at the error message. The compiler not just states an error, it also tells where the error occurred. That's where you need to focus on.

Comment: @Dren how would I make it visible to the other methods?

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Also, I don't think it is a good idea to use `JOptionPane` in a JavaFX application. Maybe you should be using [Alert](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the local variable `cust1` which you declare in one method from another method. If you want to use it in different methods, declare it as a class field.

Comment: sorry this will be a stupid question but how would I do that?

Comment: _If you want to use it in different methods, declare it as a class field_ possible but very suboptimal. If you __really__ need to access is from another class, add api :)

Comment: @OP - not stupid, just an indication that it's a good time to work through a tutorial on java language basics :)